# Is it possible to add comments to page/components while publishing?

Tags: content-delivery, sdl-tridion

When we update any page/component in tridion we can just see who has last updated, but it is not possible to add the details like why that update was made. We would like to add this as comment for each page/component modification. So that when we see the history we should also be able to see the comments. Is there a way we can do this in tridion?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/ItemCommenting

Comment: And that looks like an Answer to me.

Comment: @RajKumar it is good to know about 2011 power tools. How to implement that in the system.Can I get the implementation code or help somewhere?

Comment: see the first link.  http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Tridion+2011+power+tools

Answer (score 6):

Short answer is no. Not out of the box anyway. You could look at a GUI extension (I'm sure one was started in the [Alchemy Plugin Framework](http://www.alchemywebstore.com/) and, as Raj indicates there was one in the [2011 Power Tools](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/ItemCommenting)) - you've not indicated in your question your version.

Consider

- how would it best appear (e.g. a specific tab)
- what about localization (and, of course, unlocalization) - when should data be purged
- who would it be accessible to (and who would be ?*forced*? to enter it)
- is someone going to want to report on it (consider then storage, access, format, consistency of terminology etc.)

Would be interested to hear more on your decision(s) on progress here too :)

Answer (score 2):

Please do some homework/search before asking questions on Trex.

Power tools link: https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/ItemCommenting

Installation guide: https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/InstallationGuide